# Exporting .csv file in ssis with seperated columns

Tags: c#, ssis

I have ssis package.

And i can successfully export .csv file to local folder.
In my package i have db connection and getting columns from stored procedure. But while exporting data to .csv file all columns stands togetger by separated commas.

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can i fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to open CSV using excel, use `;` for value/column delimiter instead of `,` for separate value in each column.

And yes, CSV stands for Comma Separated Value, but excel read it as a single value.

I had same issues a few days ago...